# C++ Templates, Polymorphism, and Template Covariance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, wrapper, covariance

I have a "wrapper" template that looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
  virtual T* get() = 0;
}
```

Then I have the following inheritance scheme:

```
class A {
  // things
}

class B : public A {
  // more things
}
```

I have another class that uses that wrapper:

```
class Worker {
  void work(Wrapper<A>* wa){
    A* a = wa->get();
    //do stuff with a.
  }
}
```

All that can be done with `A*`, can be done with `B*`, but i cannot pass a `Wrapper<B>*` as a `Wrapper<A>*` to Worker. Is there a way to allow this?

I have read about C++ concepts, but I don't see how they might solve the problem.

Comment: You can try and get some insights from `std::shared_ptr`. If you could pass the wrapper by value, then a `wrapper<A>` could be made constructible from a `wrapper<B>`. Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr, point 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each class reports its base:

```
class A {
  using Base = void;
  // things
}

class B : public A {
  using Base = A;
  // more things
}
```

You could do

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapper : public EmptyForVoid<T::Base>::Type
```

And use `EmptyForVoid` for the base class selection:

```
template<typename T>
struct EmptyForVoid { using Type = T; };

template<>
struct EmptyForVoid<void> { struct Type {}; };
```

This will make `Wrapper`s follow the same inheritance tree as the types they wrap.

Comment: @gd1: If there is more than one base this becomes more complicated. About the `shared_ptr` it is preferred, but I don't know if is the OPs use case.

Comment: Guess we should know what the OP is actually trying to do. There might be a simple solution.

Comment: I think this solution has all kinds of issues. It's obviously error prone. It violates separation of concerns because `B` is declaring how `Wrapper` will use it, but `B` does not depend on `Wrapper`. And `Wrapper<T>` not returning a `T*` from `get` is pretty error prone and surprising. When you write a method somewhere else in the code that takes a `Wrapper<B>` and expects to get a `B*`...

Comment: It looks like this is the kind of solution I was looking for. It will take some time to test it, but it looks pretty good. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it directly, because C++ does not have covariance. In C++ where methods are not virtual by default (unlike Java, and I'm guessing C#), it's not clear if this would be an awesome idea (and the language is already very complicated). Basically what you have to do is have a thin templated wrapper on `work`:

```
class Worker {
public:
  template <class T>
  void work(Wrapper<T>* wa){
    work_on_a(wa->get());
  }
private:
  void work_on_a(A* a) { // do stuff with a}
}
```

This is still safe as this will only compile if the wrapped type is derived from A or otherwise defines an implicit conversion to `A`, otherwise the function call to `work_on_a` will fail.

You can do more sophisticated things here with various pros and cons, but this keeps the code as simple as possible, and minimizes template bloat.

Although note, that if `work` also needs to be virtual, this will not work (since virtual functions cannot be templates), and things will get hairy fast.

Another way to go, is to argue that the wrapper should not be passed into `work` at all; if all you need to do work is a pointer to `A`, then that's all you should pass in. But depending on your real code that may not be an option, or not make sense.

Comment: This is an example of how infectious templates can be. You have a template class and if you're not careful everything becomes templated. I'd try and stop this if possible. They did a pretty good job with `std::shared_ptr`, and even if the problem is not the same, maybe the wrapper is lightweight enough to be converted from `wrapper<B>` to `wrapper<A>`.

Comment: @gd1 That's true, but the only real downside to a template here is if it only needs to be virtual. Otherwise it's pretty trivial. If the wrapper is really that lightweight though, then it comes back to the other point in my answer: you should not be accepting the wrapper most likely, but simply a pointer (or better, reference) to `A`.

Answer (score -1):

How about a bit of the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern):

```cpp
class SubBase {
    virtual T* get() { /* default impl. */ }
};

template <typename T>
class Base : public SubBase {};

template <typename T>
class Wrapper : public Base<T> {
    virtual T* get() = 0;
}
```

… I don’t know what your inheritance graph looks like, but as long as your wrapped `T` types don’t have a `get()` method, this should work.

---

EDIT: this simple snippet doesn’t work, nor is it really CRTP, as has been pointed out; I could only make an example of this sort work after [fairly significant modification](http://ideone.com/mGrGA1).

Comment: It's not CRTP at all.

Comment: @gd1 would not `static_cast<Wrapper<B>*>(wrapper_a_ptr)` work, provided `static_cast<B*>(a_ptr)` was well-defined?

Comment: In your design `Wrapper<B>` and `Wrapper<A>` are not related. I don't see how that would work, but maybe I am tired! Try that in a compiler if you can.

Comment: You keep on changing it, so my comments are probably going to get stale and not be relevant any more. I don't know about this last version but it doesn't look OK.

Comment: @gd1 pardon me – I am composing an ideone.com test case (with the current example, with the common sub-base type) right now!

Comment: @gd1 You’re right – if you have a look at http://ideone.com/mGrGA1 I was able made it work but only after a number of frankly haphazard changes